# NSRegularExpression does not match anything after CRLF. Why?

Tags: swift

In Swift 4.2, NSRegularExpression does not match anything after CRLF. Why?

```
let str = "\r\nfoo"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "foo")
print(regex.firstMatch(in: str, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count))) // => nil
```

If you remove "\r" or "\n", you get a instance of NSTextCheckingResult.

Comment: It's a range issue. Use `NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count)` instead. If you used `\r\nfoooooooooooo` (I explicitly add extra char), you would have found it. It's just that your range calculation doesn't cover the "full string range".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 4 a new initializer of `NSRange` was introduced to convert reliably `Range<String.Index>` to `NSRange`.

Use it always, it solves your issue.

```
let str = "\r\nfoo"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "foo")
print(regex.firstMatch(in: str, range: NSRange(str.startIndex..., in: str)))
```